# for loop not saving data in variable

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, for-loop

I'm trying to create a string (foo2) which will have all the string object in the fooArray. I don't understand why the below posted code doesn't do that for me.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *foo =@"This is just a test";
    NSArray *fooArray = [foo componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    for(int i=0; i < fooArray.count; i++)
    {
        _foo2= [_foo2 stringByAppendingString:[ fooArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    NSLog(_foo2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because you are not initializing `_foo2` anywhere before `viewDidLoad` runs.  And since _foo2 hasn't been initialized and is still a nil pointer, every time you send the `stringByAppendingString:` message to it, the result is still nil.

You can fix this by initializing _foo2 to a new NSMutableString object before your loop.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *foo =@"This is just a test";
    NSArray *fooArray = [foo componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    _foo2 = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for(int i=0; i < fooArray.count; i++)
    {
        _foo2= [_foo2 stringByAppendingString:[ fooArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    NSLog(_foo2);
}
```

Comment: Using NSMutableString here is kinda superfluous: `stringbyAppendingString:` creates a new string with its argument appended to the contents of the receiver, so it doesn't matter whether the receiver is mutable. What's more, using `alloc` to create it means it gets leaked in the first iteration of the loop (unless you're using ARC, which isn't yet safe to assume). And on top of all that, you don't necessarily need a loop at all, depending on just what @Niels is trying to accomplish. There's too much to go into detail in a comment; see my answer for the full story.

Comment: I have posted a new question with more detail. Hopefully that will be easier to understand :) The new question is: Parser over txt document in xcode

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is strip spaces from the string, consider:

```
_foo2 = [foo stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
// or whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet, if that fits your use case better
```

If you want to be a little more specific, there's:

```
_foo2 = [foo stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Or to more closely follow the semantics of what you're doing, there's:

```
NSArray *fooArray = [foo componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
_foo2 = [fooArray componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

And if for some reason you really want to loop through it (perhaps to do some processing of each word?), there's a couple of ways to do that:

```
NSArray *fooArray = [foo componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

_foo2 = [NSMutableString string];
for (int i = 0; i < fooArray.count; i++) {
    [_foo2 appendString:[fooArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

Or:

```
NSArray *fooArray = [foo componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

_foo2 = @""; // equivalent to [NSString string]
for (int i = 0; i < fooArray.count; i++) {
    _foo2 = [_foo2 stringByAppendingString:[fooArray objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

(And that's not even considering fast enumeration, aka the `for..in` construct.) The first loop is probably more efficient, since I imagine repeatedly appending to the same NSMutableString is cheaper than creating new strings and tossing old ones as we go along.

Comment: What is was really trying to do was to read a text document into a NSarray and then get words out of it, which I wanted. Do you know if there is any way to go through a array and look at each word as an individual? So that once i go to a special word, i could get the index of that and choose the words before that index? My big problem is there is linebreaks in the this text document too...

Comment: In those loops, `[fooArray objectAtIndex:i]` is a string containing only the *i*th word... you can examine it however you like. If it's a word you want, the words before it are at indexes `0` through `i - 1` in fooArray... `subarrayWithRange:` might help you do something with them, depending on what you want to do. Edit your question or post another describing in detail what you're after and we can provide more detailed answers.